# Testing Database Connectivity

Tags: database, hosting

I am working on a server which supports different database types (connection via front-end), and I'm not sure what is the best approach to host databases for testing (Unit testing).
is it AWS Free tier? or somewhere else? maybe some different approach?

Answer (score 1):

If this is only for development and testing, have you considered using Docker? I've recently switched from dedicated Virtual Machines to Docker containers for this purpose, and it definitely made life easier.

This link explains how you can get a Postgres database running in a Docker container: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

This link does the same for mysql: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

The following link may also be useful: https://vsupalov.com/database-in-docker/

> Should you run databases in Docker? If you’re doing so in your
>   development environment, there’s nothing to be concerned about.
>
> You don’t have important data to lose. In case anything goes wrong,
>   you simply recreate your environment from scratch. (You can get your
>   dev env up in a single command, right?)
>
> Let’s look at a few upsides of using containers in this setting:
>
> ```
> There’s less clutter on your development machine
> You can work on multiple projects side by side, which depend on slightly different database versions
> You can create a development environment on any OS in a reliable fashion
> Everything is “documented” through automation and reproducible
> ```